# how to display PDF choosing by user then, how to save from html to PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to display  PDF in HTML tag, then convert from HTML and save as PDF

I have tried to display PDF in an embed tag, but whenever I want to convert from HTML to PDF, the saved PDF is empty.

Comment: You want to embed a pdf and then create another pdf from that?

Comment: why ? was the embedded pdf created by your code ?  The HTML <embed> element embeds external content at the specified point in the document  . Is there anything  in your html other than emebed pdf  ?

Comment: basically i want to do a web PDF editor. so i need to display PDF ,edit on it (add red div for example)and then save it as PDF

Comment: no there is nothing except import PDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the jsPDF library?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.1/jspdf.debug.js" ></script>

var doc = new jsPDF( 'p', 'px', pdfHeight, pdfWidth);
doc.addImage( $(".myPDFElement").src, 'PNG', 0, 0);
doc.save( 'MyPDF.pdf' );
```